# PHP running Drupal benchmark is slower than it should be

Tags: php, bash, drupal, benchmarking

Originally, I posted this on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/349456)... but perhaps it is more of a PHP lingual question.

I have a server with Dual Xeon Quad Core L5420 running at 2.5GHz. I've been optimizing my server, and have come to my final bottleneck: PHP.

My very simple PHP script:

./test.php

```
<?php print_r(posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid()));
```

My not-so-scientific-because-they-don't-pay-attention-to-thread-locking-but-scientific-enough-to-give-me-a-reasonable-multithreaded-requests-per-second-result scripts:

./benchmark-php

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  LIMIT=10
else
  LIMIT=$1
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
  SCRIPT="index.php"
else
  SCRIPT=$2
fi

START=$(date +%s.%N)
COUNT=0
while (( $COUNT < $LIMIT ))
do
  php $SCRIPT > /dev/null
  COUNT=$(echo "$COUNT + 1" | bc)
done
END=$(date +%s.%N)
DIFF=$(echo "$END - $START" | bc)
REQS_PER_SEC=$(echo "scale=2; $COUNT / $DIFF" | bc)
echo $REQS_PER_SEC
```

./really-benchmark-php

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  LIMIT=10
else
  LIMIT=$1
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
  THREADS=16
else
  THREADS=$2
fi

if [ -z $3 ]; then
  SCRIPT="index.php"
else
  SCRIPT=$3
fi

PIDS=""

echo '' > results
for thread in `seq 1 $THREADS`; do
  ./benchmark-php $LIMIT $SCRIPT >> results &
  PIDS="$PIDS $!"
done

for PID in $PIDS; do
  wait $PID
done

RESULTS=`cat results`
MATH="0"
for RESULT in $RESULTS; do
  MATH="$MATH + $RESULT"
done

echo "$MATH" | bc
```

The result of running `./really-benchmark-php 100 8 test.php` is ~137 requests per second.

Running the same script on a sqlite or mysql powered instance of Drupal returns ~1.5 req/s.

I have APC and mem_cache both installed, and I have verified that they're running on defaults. (Yes, APC's enable_cli is on, also.) Does someone know the magic "make PHP execute faster" switch?

I have an alternative configuration setup (FPM/FastCGI) that serves ~140 req/s of the MySQL Drupal install... how could that be possible if PHP itself can't even serve 2 req/s from the command line?

The result of the `ab` tool feel just as low to me:

static page: `ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://x.x.x.x/` Requests per second: 683.71

test php: `ab -n 100 -c 5 http://x.x.x.x/` Requests per second: 41.38

drupal-mysql: `ab -n 100 -c 10 http://x.x.x.x/drupal/` Requests per second: 0.24

drupal-sqlite: `ab -n 100 -c 10 http://x.x.x.x/drupal-test/` Requests per second: 4.92

Comment: What distro are you running? I know that some distros (CentOS specifically, but there are others) still ship with really poorly optimized php.ini settings.

Comment: Gentoo Linux, I promise I've tweaked every setting available to me. My  server is hardly skimming the surface of its capabilities based on reporting by Munin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Drupal Core (unoptimized, uncached, without APC is terrible for performance/page views per second).

**Long story short. Use Varnish or some other reverse proxy cache.**

Overall, pretty impressive. I managed a percentage increase of 167407.84% in the amount of page requests I could handle per second.

```
Start: 0.51
End : 854.29
```

Here is the difference in performance and

Here is some relevant snippets from my post that shows the different numbers.

## Test 1 (Get the Starting Benchmark)

Run an apache benchmark

`ab -k -n 100 -c 100 -g step1.txt http://example.com/how-it-works`

Okay, so this request totally killed my server.
See the graph below.

[image]

So then I decided to reduce the Requests in order to just figure out the bog standard requests per second. I went with 100 requests, with a level of 2 concurrency.

And came out with this:

```
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   197.855 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Requests per second: 0.51 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request: 3957.105 [ms] (mean)
```

## Test 2 APC Enabled

I then repeated the test but with APC enabled.

```
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   87.270 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      2138900 bytes
HTML transferred:       2096300 bytes
Requests per second:    1.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1745.396 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       872.698 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

As you can see, this is visibly better. But still **awful**. 1 request per second!? lol. That is horrendous.

## Test 3 - Enable Drupal Core Caching

I then enabled Drupal Core Caching... and repeated the apache benchmark

`ab -k -n 100 -c 5 -g test2-c5-k.txt http://example.com/how-it-works`

```
Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   23.229 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      1923002 bytes
HTML transferred:       1880900 bytes
Requests per second:    4.30 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       464.580 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       232.290 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          80.84 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

So now I ended up with 4 requests per second. Which is significantly better but still generally sucks.

The final step, add a reverse proxy cache application into the mix. What do I want to see?.. I actually don’t care, anything *must* be better than 4 requests per second. If I can get it to around 300 requests per second, then I will be pleased. Anything close to 1000 requests I’ll be ecstatic.

This is what I ended up with:

```
Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   11.706 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    10000
Total transferred:      190260000 bytes
HTML transferred:       185140000 bytes
Requests per second:    854.29 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       351.168 [ms] (mean)
```

Overall, pretty impressive. I managed a percentage increase of **167407.84%** in the amount of page requests I could handle per second.

```
Start: 0.51
End : 854.29
```

And additional I reduced the page loading time per request from  1978ms to 1.17ms (concurrently) which is a overall speed gain of … *a lot*.  A speed decrease of 99.94%. Ouch.

[image]

[image]